# How to change CSS style upon clicking button with JS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of my nav bar upon clicking a button. It has to be on multiple pages so i thought using CSS would be the best way. But i have no idea how to do it.

im trying to change the color of a unordered list

```
<ul id="tm-menu" class="tm-menu menu">
</ul>
```

How do i change the .menu style "background-color" with jQquery?

Comment: I need it to work across multiple web pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using simple jquery addClass() or removeClass() method you can achieve this effect.

Or If you want to switch the class on button click , you can below code.

```
/*Switch the classes on Button click*/
$("button").click(function(){
 $( "ul.menu" ).toggleClass("tm-menu, newclass");
}); 


/*Add or Remove the Class on Click*/
$("button").click(function(){
 $( "ul.menu" ).removeClass( "tm-menu" ).addClass( "newclass" );
});

<ul id="tm-menu" class="tm-menu menu">
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
  <li>Option 4</li>
  <li>Option 5</li>
</ul>
  <button value="Hitme">Hit Me</button>
```

Here is the Working Demo link. http://jsbin.com/curidivo/1/

Comment: wow, this works great! thanks. how would i go about doing it by clicking a specific div?

Comment: you can achieve the same thing by clicking on div. `<div id="button">Hit Me</div>`

`$("div#button").click(function(){
 $( "ul.menu" ).removeClass( "tm-menu" ).addClass( "newclass" );
});`

Comment: If this work for you then close this answer by accepting the answer.

Comment: i need it to be working on multiple pages. So on the home page i can choose a color then browse the site while that color. If there are other ways of doing this, please let me know. It doesnt need to be this method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Used to `.addClass()` **[Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**

**Css**

```
.menuBackground{
background:red;
}
```

**jquery code**

```
$('#tm-menu').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('menuBackground');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say .button is the class for your button and .blue is your class for new background color for the menu.

/*-------------------Jquery Code------------*/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.button').click(function(){
$('.menu').addClass('blue');
});
});
```

/*---------------------Css----------------*/

```
.blue{
background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .addClass() or .css()

```
$('.menu').addClass('someClass'); //preferred method
```

or

```
$('.menu').css( "background-color", "#f00" );
```

JS:

```
$('.thebutton').on('click',function(){
   $('.menu').addClass('someClass'); //replace with options above
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.buttonClass').click(function(){
        $('.menu').addClass('className');
   });
});
```

check [**addclass**](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)  and [**click**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)